# telerik controls in xamarin.android c# visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I have a native android app project using Xamarin.Android(Not cross-platform). My question is, if it is possible to add a library and use Telerik controls(I need a Gauge for instance). I did some research and I found some things about android studio, but I'm using Visual Studio and c#.

Comment: I found this link https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/xamarin/nativecontrols/android/gauges/gauges-getting-started  ,but when I run my program I get this error `in <declare-styleable> GaugeScale, unable to find attribute strokeColor` and some similar for other elemnts of the gauge.

Comment: If you need some charts, which are for free, you might check out: https://github.com/aloisdeniel/Microcharts , which uses SkiaSharp (cross-platform, but can be used for xamarin.android as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I didn't have the necessary libraries.